# 0 is evaluation to less than 0 in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to append a value to the end of each row of a csv file depending on the value of a specific cell.  If it is negative then I want it to append "-1" and if it is positive I want it to append "1".

My issue is that I also want it to append "1" if the row has a value of 0.  No matter what I try, I keep getting "-1" appended when this cell is 0.  I've tried adding an extra condition for if is 0 or if == 0 but none of this seems to work (the things that do work prevent all the correct data being appended with "-1". 
 The data in the csv is actually stored as .000000, but comparing to this string has the same issue as comparing to 0.  Incredibly stuck and any help is much appreciated.

```
with open('TransactionFilled.csv', 'r') as infile, open('Transactions.csv', 'w+',newline='') as outfile:
reader = csv.reader(infile)
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
for row in reader:
    if row[18] < '0':
        row.append('-1')
        writer.writerow(row)
    else:
        row.append('1')
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You are comparing strings here, not numbers. `'.0000' < '0'` because `'.' < '0'`

Comment: Thanks alot!  Solved the whole thing by comparing to .0000000 rather than 0!  Also learned a useful bit of python logic, so much gratitude.

Comment: Dont do that. Convert your `row[18]` to a number and compare numbers!

Answer (score 2):

This assumes row[18] holds an integer, not a float:

```
with open('TransactionFilled.csv', 'r') as infile, open('Transactions.csv', 'w+',newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row[18].isdigit() and int(row[18]) < 0:
            row.append('-1')
            writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            row.append('1')
            writer.writerow(row)
```

If you have non-ints in `row[18]` you can use `float(row[18])` to convert it to a float instead - string.isdigit() will not work then, so you might need to guard against conversion problems otherwise:

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        if float(row[18]) < 0:
            row.append('-1')
            writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            row.append('1')
            writer.writerow(row)
    except ValueError:
        # append whatever you would like to append if no float is convertable
```

Comment: now the broad exception statement is fine in this case I feel just typing ValueError is not too difficult, other than that good response.